# MavenReportException: JAVA_HOME not correctly set

Tags: java, maven, deployment, maven-plugin

I've tried many JDK versions in order to solve this problem but it seems no matter which java i'm using the outcome is always the same.

> MavenReportException: Error while creating archive: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set.

### Debug

These are the jdk's currently installed:
[image]

I ran :

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

`java -version`:

```java
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

`javac -version`

```java
javac 1.8.0_265
```

### mvn clean deploy -P release

[image]

> MavenReportException: Error while creating archive: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set.

### Maven Plugin Configuration

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Although `which java` and `which javadoc` pointing to `/usr/bin` could that be the issue?

### Edit 1

Contents of `/bin`

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/` contains a `javadoc` tool?

Comment: It does, i'm updating the question with it.

Comment: Remove the configuration for javac in your maven-compiler-plugin. If JAVA_HOME is set correctly it's simply superfluous. Check where java is coming from via `which java` ?

Comment: I did but didn't change the outcome, `which java` gives `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: Remove the settings from your PATH and only set JAVA_HOME not in the PATH...

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this helps, but in my case maven
`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.2.0:jar` and gave an exception:
`MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set.`

The solution was to find the plugin that was causing the issue,
`<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>` in my case and add the following:

```xml
                <configuration>
                    <javadocExecutable>${java.home}/bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable>
                </configuration>
```

where `${java.home}` was `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/`.

The plugin looked like:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <javadocExecutable>${java.home}/bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and the goal was executed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the java version for Maven using the following command:

#mvn --version

It will give something like:

Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-25T01:19:05+05:30)
Maven home: /home/user/apache-maven-3.5.3
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/user/jdk1.8.0_121/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8

Here, you can see which JAVA version is used and its location.

Comment: Although the variable is `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_261-amd64` `mvn --version` gives `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` which doesn't contain a javac

Comment: i fixed it now it points to the correct one but still it can not run `mvn deploy -P release`

Comment: The issue is that I can not change the `JAVA_HOME` variable of mvn -version